# Why is array_filter() not modifying the input array by reference like sort() does?

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, pass-by-reference, array-filter

Sorry but why can't this work:

```
function filter($var) {
    return($var['id'] < 4);
}

$t1 = array(
array("key"=>"date", "value"=>"effe", "id"=>2),
array("key"=>"date2", "value"=>"jieffe", "id"=>3),
array("key"=>"date3", "value"=>"efjife", "id"=>4),
array("key"=>"date4", "value"=>"effijoe", "id"=>5),

);

array_filter($t1, "filter");

var_dump($t1);
```

tested on http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: how did u do it in 1 ms like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

array_filter() ***returns*** the filtered array, it's not pass by reference:

```
$t1 = array_filter($t1, "filter");

var_dump($t1);// done
```

Comment: this one also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227240/php-array-filter-changes-data-format