# Php: array_filter changes data format

Tags: php, arrays, json, filter

In the code below I would expect

```
t2: [{"value":"".....}, {}, {}]
```

but instead I get

```
t2: {"0":{"value":"",.. , "1":{}, .. }
```

even casting

```
json_encode( (array) $t2);
```

doesn't make it work
thx

```
function filter($var) {
    return($var->id < 4);
}

$t1=json_decode('[{"value":"","id":"0","key":"algo"},{"value":"0.8","id":"-1","key":"cout"},{"value":"2012-07-21","id":"3","key":"date"},{"value":"","id":"0","key":"europe"},{"value":"","id":"0","key":"inria"},{"value":"1","id":"4","key":"ndOfRates"},{"value":"part","id":"0","key":"offre"},{"value":"","id":"0","key":"paris"},{"value":"Ut enim quisque sibi plurimum confidit et ut quisque maxime virtute et sapientia sic munitus est, ut nullo egeat suaque omnia in se ipso posita iudicet, ita in amicitiis expetendis colendisque maxime excellit. Quid enim? Africanus indigens mei? Minime hercule! ac ne ego quidem illius; sed ego admiratione quadam virtutis eius, ille vicissim opinione fortasse non nulla, quam de meis moribus habebat, me dilexit; auxit benevolentiam consuetudo. Sed quamquam utilitates multae et magnae consecutae sunt, non sunt tamen ab earum spe causae diligendi profectae. Hae duae provinciae bello quondam piratico catervis mixtae praedonum a Servilio pro consule missae sub iugum factae sunt vectigales. et hae quidem regiones velut in prominenti terrarum lingua positae ob orbe eoo monte Amano disparantur. Ultima Syriarum est Palaestina per intervalla magna protenta, cultis abundans terris et nitidis et civitates habens quasdam egregias, nullam nulli cedentem sed sibi vicissim velut ad perpendiculum aemulas: Caesaream, quam ad honorem Octaviani principis exaedificavit Herodes, et Eleutheropolim et Neapolim itidemque Ascalonem Gazam aevo superiore exstructas. Post hoc impie perpetratum quod in aliis quoque iam timebatur, tamquam licentia crudelitati indulta per suspicionum nebulas aestimati quidam noxii damnabantur. quorum pars necati, alii puniti bonorum multatione actique laribus suis extorres nullo sibi relicto praeter querelas et lacrimas, stipe conlaticia victitabant, et civili iustoque imperio ad voluntatem converso cruentam, claudebantur opulentae domus et clarae. Et quoniam apud eos ut in capite mundi morborum acerbitates celsius dominantur, ad quos vel sedandos omnis professio medendi torpescit, excogitatum est adminiculum sospitale nequi amicum perferentem similia videat, additumque est cautionibus paucis remedium aliud satis validum, ut famulos percontatum missos quem ad modum valeant noti hac aegritudine colligati, non ante recipiant domum quam lavacro purgaverint corpus. ita etiam alienis oculis visa metuitur labes.","id":"4","key":"text"},{"value":"on","id":"0","key":"type"}]');

$t2 = array_filter($t1, "filter");

echo 't2: '.json_encode($t2);
```

Comment: dose the json_encode($t1) give the same problem? and how about json_encode(array_values($t2))?

Comment: no t1: [{"value":"","id":"0","key":"algo"},{"value":"0.8","id":"-1","key":"cout"},{"value":"2012-07-21","id":"3","key":"date"},{"value":"","id":"0","key":"europe"},{"value":"","id":"0","key":"inria"},{"value":"1","id":"4","key":"ndOfRates"},{"value":"part","id":"0","key":"off.......  that's why this is strange

Comment: json_encode(array_values($t2)) seems good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, there is no difference between associative and numeric arrays. Therefore, when converting to JSON, `json_encode` has to infer from the array's keys whether it should be encoded as an array or an object. It does this by testing to see if (a) the keys are numeric and (b) if they are sequential, starting with `0`; if both tests pass, it will be encoded as an array.

When you use `array_filter`, you remove some of the keys. The others are not renumbered, so the keys are no longer sequential.  This means that `json_encode` infers that this should be an object rather than an array when encoded in JSON.

You can correct this by renumbering the keys. Use `array_values` to do this:

```
echo 't2: '.json_encode(array_values($t2));
```